# How to use Raspberry PI (with extra hardware, if needed) to simulate peripheral USB devices like camera,mouse, keyboard

Tags: usb

I know that Model A and Zero of RP can simulate storage devices. For one of my projects I would like to be able to simulate keyboard, mouse and even a webcam. Is this possible using RP, even if I need additional hardware. What i want is to be able to provide video stream which is programmable along with keyboard/mouse.

Comment: A RP is normally not connected using USB, so this seems not so easy. You should probably be looking for an Arduino Leonardo, which can report itself as mouse or keyboard and create clicks on the PC.

Comment: Is there an Arduino/RP  compatible micro-controller that can report as any device and actually be able to handle the data stream?

Comment: There is stuff online about using the zero as a HID ("human interface device": keyboard, mouse).  Camera is probably in theory possible but I have not heard of any software around to implement it.